# Can't "warm up" Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I know, there are many of this questions, but none of them could solve my issue.

I got a REST API. I'm currently trying to solve an issue where the first request to the server takes like 10 seconds and the following request like 3 seconds. After it gets warm, it gets cold again after like 20min. I can't find a way to solve this issue.

I read about cold queries etc, but non of them helped me. To solve it, I did this in my startup.cs

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    WakeupDB(services);
}

private void WakeupDB(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        var cs = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ICalendarService>();
        var mrs = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IMetadataRepository>();

        while (true)
        {
            _ = cs.GetCalendarAsync(new DateTime(2020, 4, 1), new DateTime(2020, 4, 30));
            _ = mrs.GetEmployeesAsync();
            _ = mrs.GetGroupsAsync();
            await Task.Delay(300000); // 5 Minutes
        }
    });
}
```

First I tried without the infinite loop, but as mentioned the request slow down again after like 20 minutes or so. So I did the infinite loop to "keep it warm".

But none of them actually had a positive impact on performance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have to ask, are you really sure it's the database that's going to sleep? It seems more logical that the actual application is going to sleep. With IIS this is caused by the default settings for example.

Comment: Yes, application pool recycling is the prime suspect. Also, it's not clear what the lifetime of your services is. Maybe they don't get cold, but their contexts get bloated.

Comment: @Dennis1679 i don't actually know. I googled about that and found the solution I wrote. Do you have any ressources about that which I could read please?

Comment: Are you guys talking about this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771956(v=ws.10) ?

Comment: @MucoBey; It's your Hardware / OS problem, I don't have problems like this in many years of using EF Core in developing / production environments. EF6 is a little bit laggy but EF Core is fast as hell.

Comment: Changing the IIS idle timeout didn't help